# Unable to pull images from insecure registry through minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, docker-registry

I have a local insecure docker registry which I created using the command:

```sh
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2`
```

I have added this to the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` as well. I tagged several images in the format `localhost:5000/<orgname>/<imagename>:<tag>` and pushed them to the insecure registry.

When I run `curl -X GET localhost:5000/v2/_catalog` I can see that they are available inside the local registry.

I started minikube with the command `minikube start --insecure-registry="localhost:5000"`. Here, my default driver is docker (I also tried with kvm2). I enabled the registry addon as well using the command `minikube addons enable registry`

I have a configmap which states the image in the format I mentioned earlier. When I apply this using `kubectl`, I get an `ImagePullBackoff` error with the error message

```sh
Failed to pull image "localhost:5000/org/product:tag": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for localhost:5000/org/product:tag not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Docker version: `19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0`

Minikube version: `1.9.2`

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by replacing localhost with my IP.

```
minikube start --insecure-registry="<IP-of-your-computer>:5000"
```

Have to use the IP instead of localhost when tagging and pushing images to te local registry as well.

Comment: Getting the error while pushing the image to local registry: `Get https://<computer-ip>:5000/v2/: dial tcp 192.168.1.10:5000: connect: connection refused`

Answer (score 1):

Well, the minikube K8s subnet is different from the one that your registry is running so `localhost` is not going to work without some tweaks. I recommend following the [minikube official guide](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/registry/) and not run:

```sh
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2`
```

In essence, it says that after running:

```sh
minikube addons enable registry
```

Then when you create your minikube instance

```
minikube start --drive=docker --insecure-registry "10.0.0.0/24"
```

Comment: You mean I delete my existing registry container and then try with the above command? If I delete the minikube instance, I'd have to repeat these steps again right?

Comment: does this work on Ubuntu?  I'm seeing `2020/07/16 10:10:51 socat[9] E connect(5, AF=2 172.17.0.2:5000, 16): Connection refused` when I try to push an image to the registry.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize you were running Ubuntu. The socat is only for mac and windows. Updated the answer. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I used following on Ubuntu 20.04

1. Start the minikube with insecure-registry as your computer's ip:
   `minikube start --insecure-registry="<your-computer-ip>:5000"`
2. Enable the registry:
   `minikube addons enable registry`
3. make sure registry is up and running:
   `kubectl get service --namespace kube-system`

```
> NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                AGE
> kube-dns   ClusterIP   10.96.0.10     none          53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP 54m
> registry   ClusterIP   10.98.34.133   none          80/TCP,443/TCP         37m
```

4. Portforward to localhost:
   `kubectl port-forward --namespace kube-system service/registry 5000:80`
5. Build and push your images to localhost
   `docker tag my/image localhost:5000/myimage`
   `docker push localhost:5000/myimage`
6. Use the image in deployment yaml and apply using kubectl
   in yaml file:

```
containers:
        - name: app-name
          image: localhost:5000/image-name:latest
```